# Combine rows with duplicate identifiers while adding additional columns

Tags: r, dataframe, excel-formula, data-cleaning

Here's a simple example of what I'm looking for:

Before:

```
data.frame(
  Name = c("pusheen", "pusheen", "puppy"),
  Species = c("feline", "feline", "doggie"),
  Activity = c("snacking", "napping", "playing"),
  Start = c(1, 2, 3),
  End = c(11, 12, 13)
)
```

After:

```
data.frame(
  Name = c("pusheen", "puppy"),
  Species = c("feline", "doggie"),
  Activity1 = c("snacking", "playing"),
  Start1 = c(1, 3),
  End1 = c(11, 13),
  Activity2 = c("napping", NA),
  Start2 = c(2, NA),
  End2 = c(12, NA)
)
```

How do I do this in R or Excel? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `pivot_wider` from the `tidyr` package.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(num = row_number()) %>% # Create a counter by group
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c("Name", "Species"), 
    names_from = num, 
    values_from = c("Activity", "Start", "End"), 
    names_sep = "")
```

If you want the result ordered as in your sample output, we can add an additional `select` statement. I used `str_sub` from the stringr package to pull out the last character from each column name, and then sorted the names from there. This method of ordering columns should generalise to any number of activities.

```
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  select(Name, Species, names(df)[order(str_sub(names(df), -1))])
```